# Fish adb not found

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I installed fish shell on my macbook. when I try to run the command `adb` - get error fish: `Unknown command 'adb'`, though adb is added to .bash_profile. How to fix it?

~/.bash_profile

```
export ADB=:/Users/mancj/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
export PATH=$ADB:$PATH
```

**EDIT:**
I tried a `cd` in the adb folder and run the `adb` command , also get error `fish: Unknown command 'adb'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fish` doesn't care about `bash`'s startup files, see https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_startup

You need to change your `PATH` in `~/.config/fish/config.fish` instead and restart the shell.

Answer (score 3):

Within Android Studio's Terminal, run the following command:

`set PATH ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools $PATH`

This means any executable within the given path (adb in our case) can be run by its name rather than path directory.

If you're not using FISH, you can achieve the same using this command:

`export PATH="~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH`

Answer (score 2):

Use
`fish_add_path /Users/mancj/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/`
or you can add the same to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

Might need to re start the shell

Answer (score -1):

Further, it's unlikely that fish includes '.' (i.e. the CWD) in its path by default, so simply entering the directory containing the binary you want to run is not likely to work.  If that's strictly necessary, explicitly specify the path:

$ ./binary_to_run

In general, including '.' in the path is a security exploit waiting to happen.